# Is there a way to set offset between SKSpriteNode and it's physicsBody?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, physics, skphysicsbody

I am creating a game where user controls a cube (50x50px) and can collect more cubes while exploring and collected cubes added to a random side of the users current cubes.

User starting cube

http://s7.postimg.org/id95wms7r/cube.png

After user collected some more cubes

http://s13.postimg.org/oo9v4c9bb/morecubes.png

As you can already see from the second image, my problem is when I generate the body from texture, it has some offset with the original picture. Cube adding is random so you can get really weird shapes and those offsets are always different. My question is, is there a way to align that body with the parent sprite? Also I don't want to move the sprite because sprite is in the right place, I actually want to move the body.

This is how my code looks like. Both player and cubes are at CGPointZero in their own coordinate systems.

Player: SKNode

-- Cubes: SKSpriteNode

```
physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: cubes.texture, size: accumulatedSize)
physicsBody?.dynamic = true
physicsBody?.mass = 2.0
physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
```

Comment: try setting the anchorPoints to `0.5,0.5`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the SKPhysicsBody from the texture, create an SKPhysicsBody for each individual cube, then put all those individual bodies into an array, and then create the SKPhysicsBody from the bodies in that array using:

- (SKPhysicsBody *)bodyWithBodies:(NSArray *)bodies

That will get you a more accurate body with the sprite.

"The shapes of the physics bodies passed into this method are used to create a new physics body whose covered area is the union of the areas of its children" (from the SKPhysicsBody Class Reference).